# Minio Actual value of requests_max

Tags: memory, python-requests, throttling, minio

when I start minio without setting up the requests_max parameter, the deafult value is 0, and, according to documentation, when requests_max parameter is set to 0, Minio will automatically calculate the maximum number of requests depending on available memory.

*NOTE: A zero value of requests_max means MinIO will automatically calculate requests based on available RAM size and that is the default behavior.
https://github.com/minio/minio/blob/master/docs/throttle/README.md*

So, on splash screen at startup, I see the requests_max parameter calculated based on available RAM size

```
Automatically configured API requests per node based on available memory on the system: 20
```

Now my question is:
Is there a `mc` command, or any other way, to find the actual maximum request value (calculated based on available memory)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this value is not exposed in any other way (i.e. other than the log line when it is not set on server startup). You could try opening a feature request to get this item added to the server info command: `mc admin info`.

The MinIO team is available on their public slack channel or by email to answer questions 24/7/365.